# Chrome 59.0.3071 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) ERROR Uncaught Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL

Tags: macos, angular, google-chrome, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am using Jasmine and Karma for my front end unit tests. When running my tests I get the following errors:

**Terminal Error**

`Chrome 59.0.3071 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) ERROR
  Uncaught Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:9876/api/volunteer
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:2604
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Mac OS X 10.11.6): Executed 4 of 6 ERROR (0 secs / 1.02 secs)
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) ERROR
  Uncaught Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:9876/api/volunteer
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Mac OS X 10.11.6): Executed 4 of 6 ERROR (1.433 secs / 1.02 secs)`

**Browser Errors**

`SignUpComponent should be created
[object ErrorEvent] thrown
SignUpComponent form should clear on submit
[object ErrorEvent] thrown`

I cannot figure out why the terminal tells me I have a 404 error and the browser tells me I have an error within sign-up.component.spec.ts. sign-up.component.spec.ts does not make any http requests.

SignUpComponent can be found in client/app/sign-up/sign-up.component.spec.ts at the following repository:
https://github.com/cerberus-org/cerberus-app

Something I noticed when attempting to debug was if I commented out client/app/shared/volunteer.service.spec.ts all tests would pass even though the error points to client/app/sign-up/sign-up.component.spec.ts.

Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was receiving this error because the back end was not properly mocked. I did not use XHRBackend, so when other tests attempted to make an http call, the call was not intercepted and handled by the mock backend.

I was able to properly mock my backend by following this tutorial: 
https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/testing-services-in-angular-2

'The Rest' section of this tutorial was most relevant.